# Get Component Reference in AuraJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, aura.js

I'm using jQuery dataTables to display a table.  I need to be able to pass a row selection event on to my Aura component that handles the selection and performs some operations on the data from that row.

In the `initialize()` function:

```
initialize: function()
{
    $("#mytable tbody").click(function(event)
    {
      $(mytable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function ()
      {
        $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
      });

      $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
    });

    mytable = $('#mytable').dataTable();
},
```

I set up the click handler for the row selection, but how do I get a reference to the enclosing component so I can `sandbox.emit()` function to issue messages?  I can put a reference to the component into the Closure, but that essentially makes this component a singleton and I could never have two instances of the component on the page at the same time.

Is there a standard way, using jQuery selectors or some other method, that I can retrieve a reference to the enclosing component from inside the `click()` handler?

**Edit:** I should never try to write code until I have had 32oz of caffine.  You can pass a reference to the current component via the `click()` method itself.  Like so:

```
$("#mytable tbody").click(this, function(event)
{
  $(mytable.fnSettings().aoData).each(function ()
  {
    $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
  });

  $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');

  event.data.sandbox.emit('mychannel', {data: 'stuff'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try something like this

```
initialize: function () {
   var that = this;
   $("#mytable tbody").click(function(event) {
      //have acces to component as 'that'    
   });
}
```

what I used for events is view inside component configuration:

```
View: {
        events: {
            'click a[data-question-edit-id]': function (e) {
                var button = $(e.currentTarget),
                    id = button.attr('data-question-edit-id'),
                    examId = this.component.examModel.get('id');

                this.sandbox.router.navigate('/exams/' + examId + '/questions/' + id + '/edit', {trigger: true});
            },
            'click a[data-question-delete-id]': function (e) {
                var button = $(e.currentTarget),
                    id = button.attr('data-question-delete-id');

                this.component.showDeleteConfirmation(id);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you'll find be helpful, here is my repo of aura project I'm working on: 
https://github.com/lyubomyr-rudko/aura-test-project